# CSS Fill Div Height of Page

Tags: html, css

I need div bottom to fill the remaining height of the PAGE, not a parent div

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Give `min-height` to bottom , `height:100%` wont work

Comment: when writing your question you get this question as the FIRST related quesiton ... so it's good to consider the related question before posting your question

Comment: @Temani that related question makes use of a parent div, a flex container. But I did state in my question that I want to solve the solution without a parent div. Isn't that fine?

Comment: you have to read all the answer ;) not only the accepted one .. and as a side not you have a parent container here and it's called the body

Comment: @Temani Ok will do but I can't use the body. This is for an angular program with multiple components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calc` with `vh` to calculate the page's 100% height minus the `50px` from the `top` DIV.

Take a look at this snippet:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Yes this seems to do it! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try the code below, but careful, its CSS3 and may not fully supported. See https://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Alternative: With Javascript every "normal" browser will be supported, b

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: what the point of repeating the same answer ?